# Tensorflow keras model.save raises InaccessibleTensorError with custom layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.x

I have a custom keras model (using `tf.keras.model`/functional api) for which I need to save the weights and model architecture (using `keras.Model.save`).

The model uses standard keras components like dense, flatten, etc. and one particular custom layer:

```
class NormalizationLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, name=None, axis=1):
        super(NormalizationLayer, self).__init__(name=name)
        self.max = None
        self.axis = axis

    def build(self, input_shape):
        pass

    def call(self, inputs, inverse=False):
        if inverse:
            return tf.transpose(tf.math.multiply(tf.transpose(inputs), self.max))
        else:
            self.max = tf.reduce_max(inputs, axis=self.axis)
            if self.axis == 1:
                return tf.transpose(tf.math.divide_no_nan(tf.transpose(inputs), self.max))
            else:
                return tf.math.divide_no_nan(inputs, self.max)

    def get_config(self):
        custom_config = {'max': self.max,
                         'axis': self.axis}
        base_config = super(NormalizationLayer, self).get_config()
        base_config.update(custom_config)
        return base_config
```

I already added the `get_config` method when I encountered a problem in the first place. Unfortunately, when trying to save the model using `model.save`, I ran into the following error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InaccessibleTensorError: The tensor 'Tensor("Max:0", shape=(None,), dtype=float32)' cannot be accessed here: it is defined in another function or code block. Use return values, explicit Python locals or TensorFlow collections to access it. Defined in: FuncGraph(name=input_normalization_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses, id=140460908747216); accessed from: FuncGraph(name=model_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses, id=140460638991312)
```

Is my approach in general wrong, or do I oversee something. Already tried out adding `@tf.function`-decorator, but run into similar problems. Saving the weights with `model.save_weights()` works as expected.

I am using tensorflow==2.2.0rc4.

Thanks for any helping comments in advance.

Comment: Your `get_config` is wrong, the line `return base_config.update(...)` returns `None`. You should do `base_config.update(...)` and then in a new line afterwards do `return base_config`. The method `.update` returns `None`!

Comment: @bluesummers thanks for the hint, that is indeed a stupid error, I corrected it like above and tested it. Unfortunately, the error from above remains.

Comment: Why do you have `max` in your config? It is no where used in the constructor

Comment: `max` is created with `None` in the constructor's second line. Then in the `call`-method, `max` is calculated (at least if `inverse=False`) and saved under `self.max`.